# Change colors to table lines

Tags: tables

I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{orangec}{RGB}{255,158,62}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\cline{1-2}
\rowcolor{orange}\multicolumn{1}{|l}{text} &    \\ 
\cline{1-2}
\rowcolor{orangec}text & text   \\ 
\cline{1-2}
text & text   \\ 
text & text  \\ 
text & text   \\ 
\cline{1-2}
\rowcolor{orangec}text & text   \\ 
\cline{1-2}
text & text  \\ 
text & text   \\ 
text & text   \\ 
 & text  \\ 
 & text   \\ 
\cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives a table with black lines.
However, I can't change the color of the lines at will.
The result I want is this one:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` and `!{\color{orangec}\vline}` instead of `|` to change the color of a vertical rule midways:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{orangec}{RGB}{255,158,62}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{orangec}\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{orange}\multicolumn{1}{|l}{text} & \\ 
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\hline
\arrayrulecolor{orangec}
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orangec}\vline} l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}text} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orangec}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}text}  \\ 
\hline
text & text   \\ 
text & text  \\ 
text & text   \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{orangec}\vline} l !{\color{white}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}text} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{l !{\color{orangec}\vline}}{\cellcolor{orangec}text}  \\ 
\hline
text & text  \\ 
text & text   \\ 
text & text   \\ 
 & text  \\ 
 & text   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]